# What is the difference between the Fukaya category and the Fukaya-Floer category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry

What is the difference between the Fukaya category and the Fukaya-Floer category? It seems that the former is defined in terms of flat $U(1)$ line bundles and the latter in terms of flat unitary vector bundles. However, in some references, it seems that Fukaya category is used for objects which include flat unitary vector bundles as well.

Comment: I don't think there's a distinction, except that "Fukaya-Floer" is little used. Exactly what objects are allowed in a Fukaya category (what class of symplectic manifolds, Lagrangians, brane structures, algebraic enlargement, what coefficient ring) depends on the context, and will be specified in detailed accounts.

Comment: Using higher rank local systems enables you to detect non-displaceability in some cases.